# NodeJS + Express mixes concurrent requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, async-await

I'm creating a Restful API with NodeJS and express. After a request has been made, the application itself also does a request to some other api's, and updates a database.

In the beginning i thought everything worked fine, until i started testing it with 2 devices, running a HTTP Post request at closely the same time.

What i found out from my console logs was that the requests got mixed up and the app crashed.

I read somewhere that wrongly declaring global variables could cause the problem or not asyncing/awaiting in the right way.

Could someone point me out in the right direction to where i can solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```js
require('console-stamp')(console, '[HH:MM:ss.l]');
const express = require('express');
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const activeParkings = require('./modules/db-methods');
const api = require('./modules/message-api');
const parseMessage = require('./modules/parse-message');
const contentType = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'};
const moment = require('moment');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.post('/url', async (req, response) => {
  
  // Gets timestamp of current date (formatted)
  // Gets data from incoming message
  var dateTimeNow = new Date().toISOString().replace("Z", "").substr(0, 19);          
  var phoneNumber = req.body.From.replace("whatsapp", "").replace(" ", "").replace("+", "").replace(":", "");        
  var messageBody = req.body.Body;   
  var messageSID = req.body.MessageSid;

  // Validates and parses message
  var parsedMessage = parseMessage.parseMessage(messageBody);
  console.log("Message: " + parsedMessage);

  // Initialize Twilio Response
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

  // Gets parking entry from database based on phone number
  await activeParkings.getParkingByNumber(phoneNumber, async function(dbResponse) {
    console.log("Checking if sender has an active or pending parking");
    // If there is 1 entry in the database containing a pending or active parking action by phone number
    if(dbResponse.rowCount == 1) {
      
      // If the parking actino made by this phone number is pending (waiting on confirmation for daycard)
      if(dbResponse.rows[0].pending == true) {
        console.log("User has pending parking (fixed day rate)");
 
        if(parsedMessage == "y") {
          console.log("Going to start parking with fixed day rate");
          await api.startParking(dbResponse.rows[0].vrn, dbResponse.rows[0].zone, async function (parkInfo, requestStatus) {
            console.log("Parking started");
            var parkid = parkInfo.id;
            var maxDateTime = parkInfo.mdt.toString();
            var startDateTime = parkInfo.sdt.toString();
            var formatMaxDateTime = moment(maxDateTime).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss');


            console.log("Park ID: " + parkid);
            console.log("Start: " + startDateTime);
            console.log("Max End: " + maxDateTime);
            
            console.log("Going to confirm parking in database");
            await activeParkings.confirmParking(parkid, startDateTime, maxDateTime, function(res) {
              

              console.log("Parking updated in database");
              // if parking action is succesfully started
              twiml.message("message");
              response.writeHead(200, contentType);
              response.end(twiml.toString());

            });
      
          });



        } else if (parsedMessage == "n") {
          // remove from table
          twiml.message("message");
          response.writeHead(200, contentType);
          response.end(twiml.toString());
        } else {
          // hier is t fout
        }
      } else {

      // if pending is false
        if(parsedMessage == "q") {
          await api.stopParking(dbResponse.rows[0].parkid, async function(resp, httpStatus) {
            console.log(resp);
            console.log(httpStatus);
            activeParkings.removeParking(dbResponse.rows[0].parkid, function(resp2) {

              // if parking action initiated by this number is succesfully stopped
              twiml.message("message");
              response.writeHead(200, contentType);
              response.end(twiml.toString());
            })
          });
        } else {
          // if parking action is started but a weird message is sent
          twiml.message("message");
          response.writeHead(200, contentType);
          response.end(twiml.toString());
          
        }
      }

    } else {
      if(parsedMessage != false && parsedMessage.length == 2) {

        console.log("Message is in format of start parking message");
        var vrn = parsedMessage[1];            
        var zone = parsedMessage[0];      
        console.log("Retrieving zone info...");
        await api.zoneInfo(zone, async function(zoneInfo, httpStatus){
          console.log("Zone: " + zoneInfo);
          if(zoneInfo.grant == 1) {
            console.log("Fixed day rate applied to zone");
            // Hier is dagkaart actief
            // sla op in pending
            // stuur bericht terug wachten op ja/nee
            console.log("Going to insert pending parking in database");
            await activeParkings.insertParking("nan", phoneNumber, "userid", dateTimeNow, "null", zone, vrn, true, function(res) {
              console.log("Database succesfully updated");
              twiml.message("message");
              response.writeHead(200, contentType);
              response.end(twiml.toString());


            });


          } else {
            console.log("Going to start parking");
            await api.startParking(vrn, zone, function (parkInfo, requestStatus) {
              var parkid = parkInfo.id;
              var maxDateTime = parkInfo.mdt.toString();
              var startDateTime = parkInfo.sdt.toString();
              var formatMaxDateTime = moment(maxDateTime).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss');

              console.log("Parking succesfully started");
              console.log("Going to insert parking in database");
              activeParkings.insertParking(parkid, phoneNumber, "userid", startDateTime, maxDateTime, zone, vrn, false, function(res) {
                console.log("Database succesfully updated");
                // if parking action is succesfully started
                twiml.message("message");
                response.writeHead(200, contentType);
                response.end(twiml.toString());

              });
        
            });
          }
        });

            
      } else if(parsedMessage == "q") {
        twiml.message("message");
        response.writeHead(200, contentType);
        response.end(twiml.toString());
      } else {
        twiml.message("message");
        response.writeHead(200, contentType);
        response.end(twiml.toString());
      }
    } 

  });
  
}).listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));
```